# svg from sprite import as background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

In my vanilla JS project I like pulling svg images from svg sprite (which is in separated svg file). What bothers me a lot is that in this way I can only use svg images in HTML code, but I would also love to use them in css file. Is something like that even possible?

SVG sprite (located in separated file in my code). I heard that it doesn't work in tools like codepen so I only attach it here as plain text:

```
<svg width="0" height="0" class="hidden">
  <symbol id="il_uk_coverage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 61 61"><title>UK Coverage</title>  <path d="M31,1A30,30,0,1,0,61,31,30,30,0,0,0,31,1ZM50,52.53A2.81,2.81,0,0,0,50.16,50,2.86,2.86,0,0,0,49,48.65,25.23,25.23,0,0,0,33.41,5.87a2.4,2.4,0,0,0-.13-.59,2.21,2.21,0,0,0-1.75-1.41,9.65,9.65,0,0,1-1.07-.26,5.26,5.26,0,0,0-3.7-.06c-.94.44-1.33.87-2.28,3.08a25.23,25.23,0,0,0-2.25,48,2.17,2.17,0,0,0,1.9,3c1.36.08,3.12.15,4.18.19h.12a3.22,3.22,0,0,0,2.48-1.16l.38-.47A25.44,25.44,0,0,0,35,55.92a32.51,32.51,0,0,0,3.57-.12c2.1-.22,4.18-.62,6.19-1,.83-.16,1.65-.32,2.47-.46a4.58,4.58,0,0,0,.77-.21,28.9,28.9,0,1,1,2-1.58Zm-16.44.76-1.65,0a3,3,0,0,0-2.4,1.11l-.55.66a.64.64,0,0,1-.51.23c-.82,0-2.08-.08-3.23-.14L27,53.36c.09-.09.5-.58.72-.85l.1-.12c1-1.21,1.87-1.36,3.91-1.45a3.08,3.08,0,0,0,2.19-1,2.81,2.81,0,0,0,.67-1.37,1.3,1.3,0,0,0-.34-1.17,1.33,1.33,0,0,0-1.16-.37,4,4,0,0,1-.48.07,10.54,10.54,0,0,1-6.7-1.77l3-2.66a1.28,1.28,0,0,0,.35-1.46l-1.07-2.69h4.46A1.3,1.3,0,0,0,34,37.36c.17-2,.42-5-2.12-7.17a3.48,3.48,0,0,1-.26-1l-.07-.36a2.37,2.37,0,0,0-.93-1.78,2.56,2.56,0,0,0-2.1-.5L26.72,27a.43.43,0,0,1-.37-.09.47.47,0,0,1-.17-.34,10.9,10.9,0,0,1,.08-2c.29-1.81.33-4.09-2-5.74a1.13,1.13,0,0,1-.26-.28,1.33,1.33,0,0,1-.16-.83A19.84,19.84,0,0,1,25.1,12l.22-.57c1.73-4.35,2.16-5.39,2.53-5.56a3.34,3.34,0,0,1,1.92.21l.61.16a.53.53,0,0,0,0,.12h0c-.32.36-.65.72-1,1.06a4,4,0,0,0-1,4.53,1.3,1.3,0,0,0,1.5.85l5.28-1.12a1.68,1.68,0,0,1-.08,1.74,15.12,15.12,0,0,0-1.28,3.17C33.4,18,33,18.57,32.31,18.82l-.08,0a1.33,1.33,0,0,0-.48.23,1.29,1.29,0,0,0-.49,1.14v0a1.35,1.35,0,0,0,.37.85,2.33,2.33,0,0,0,.17.28A2.85,2.85,0,0,0,34,22.82a3.27,3.27,0,0,1,.5.14c1.64.92,2.27,2.49,2.72,4.57a4.87,4.87,0,0,0,3.43,4.13,1.64,1.64,0,0,1,.43.58c.65,1.37,1.26,2.8,1.84,4.19l.56,1.31a1.65,1.65,0,0,1,.12.32,1.19,1.19,0,0,1,0,.16,2.58,2.58,0,0,0,2.92,3.09c1.15-.18,1.57,0,1.91.44A4.84,4.84,0,0,1,49,43.5l.12.48-3.79,4.26A1.3,1.3,0,0,0,46,50.36l1.59.43a.26.26,0,0,1,.19.18.2.2,0,0,1,0,.2,1.23,1.23,0,0,1-.95.59l-2.51.47c-2,.38-4,.78-6,1A37.77,37.77,0,0,1,33.51,53.29ZM23,53.56a23.94,23.94,0,0,1,.81-45.42c-.27.68-.58,1.45-.94,2.37l-.23.58c-.05.12-.25.64-.48,1.41A20.37,20.37,0,0,0,11,26.86a6.2,6.2,0,0,0-1.13,2.71A1.32,1.32,0,0,0,9.9,30a1.85,1.85,0,0,0,.63.86s0,.08,0,.12A20.49,20.49,0,0,0,25.76,50.78l-.07.08-.53.64Zm5.88-24.41a2,2,0,0,0,0,.26l.06.31a4,4,0,0,0,1.08,2.41,4.26,4.26,0,0,1,1.35,3.72c-.15,0-.29,0-.43,0A4.91,4.91,0,0,1,26.11,31a5,5,0,0,1,.22-1.45,3.09,3.09,0,0,0,.91,0ZM26.53,41.36l-2.44,2.13s-.06.07-.1.1a14.39,14.39,0,0,1-7.14-9.9,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,1.3.33h0a3.15,3.15,0,0,0,1.43-.38l.11-.07.57-.38a11,11,0,0,0,6.07,7.72Zm.29,8.35a19.17,19.17,0,0,1-15-18.52,4.23,4.23,0,0,0,1.27-.45l.12-.07,0,0c.07.08.15.2.24.31a3.82,3.82,0,0,0,1.2,1.2,4.27,4.27,0,0,1,.67.42,15.66,15.66,0,0,0,8,12.08,2.49,2.49,0,0,0-.09.82,2.45,2.45,0,0,0,1.14,1.91,15.92,15.92,0,0,0,3.36,1.67A5.24,5.24,0,0,0,26.82,49.71ZM21.35,18.58a15.67,15.67,0,0,0-4.26,5.11,6.26,6.26,0,0,0-2-.3,2.56,2.56,0,0,0-1.13.3,4.17,4.17,0,0,0-.93.65,19.14,19.14,0,0,1,8.74-10.15,20.71,20.71,0,0,0-.47,3.38A4.15,4.15,0,0,0,21.35,18.58Zm-3,12.79a.41.41,0,0,1-.17.05c-.12,0-.37-.21-.67-.45A8.34,8.34,0,0,0,16,30a3.34,3.34,0,0,1-.4-.5,5.49,5.49,0,0,0-.7-.8,1.74,1.74,0,0,0-.75-.59,1.72,1.72,0,0,0-.79-.12A6.94,6.94,0,0,1,15,26.06l.11-.07a3.66,3.66,0,0,1,3.24,1.79l1.32,2.67Zm7.43,5.52a2.11,2.11,0,0,0-.21,2l0,.1a9.7,9.7,0,0,1-4.13-6.6,2.33,2.33,0,0,0,.67-2.87l-.47-.94a9.59,9.59,0,0,1,2-3.82,16.72,16.72,0,0,0-.06,1.85,3.05,3.05,0,0,0,1.15,2.29,3.61,3.61,0,0,0,.36.23A6.45,6.45,0,0,0,24.81,31a6.23,6.23,0,0,0,2.53,5A2.09,2.09,0,0,0,25.75,36.89Zm-4.92-10-.15-.29a5.72,5.72,0,0,0-2.39-2.43,14.54,14.54,0,0,1,3.53-4.31s0,0,0,0a3.5,3.5,0,0,0,.94,1,2.25,2.25,0,0,1,1,1.85A10.81,10.81,0,0,0,20.83,26.91ZM51.61,43.19c0-.1-.06-.2-.08-.3a6.69,6.69,0,0,0-1.15-2.79,4.43,4.43,0,0,0-.71-.67A20.47,20.47,0,0,0,37.87,11.7a5.81,5.81,0,0,0-1-2.18A1.3,1.3,0,0,0,35.51,9l-4.8,1a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,.45-.67c.63-.62,1.22-1.28,1.72-1.86a2.3,2.3,0,0,0,.21-.33,23.93,23.93,0,0,1,18.52,36Zm-5.78-6.47-.09-.22a15.55,15.55,0,0,0,1-5.51,15.74,15.74,0,0,0-10.1-14.68,12,12,0,0,1,.7-1.58,4.73,4.73,0,0,0,.57-1.64,19.18,19.18,0,0,1,10.6,25.75,5.18,5.18,0,0,0-2.43-.07A3,3,0,0,0,45.83,36.72Zm-4-7.33a10.88,10.88,0,0,0-4.3-7.22,7.37,7.37,0,0,0-1.83-1.48,4,4,0,0,0-1-.36,6.24,6.24,0,0,0,1.5-2.79A14.46,14.46,0,0,1,45.44,31,14.06,14.06,0,0,1,45,34.66c-.49-1.17-1-2.36-1.55-3.53A4,4,0,0,0,41.86,29.39Zm-1.48-.8A3.64,3.64,0,0,1,39.72,27l-.09-.41A10,10,0,0,1,40.38,28.59Z"></path>
  </symbol>
</svg>
```

This usage in my HTML works fine:

```
<svg class="icon-size-md" viewBox="0 0 40 40">
    <use href="../resources/icons/sprite-all.svg#coverage"></use>
</svg>
```

I would like to import that svg from sprite into my CSS code e.g. for background-image.

```
.wrapper {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: url('../resources/icons/sprite-all.svg#coverage'); // this doesn't work
}
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

But it doesn't work for me. If this wasn't possible way how to use svg from sprite in both: `<use>` and css file, is there ANY other way? (and renaming "symbol" to "g" doesn't work for me)

Comment: only SVG use elements can target SVG symbol elements.

Comment: Please read about [How SVG Fragment Identifiers Work](https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/)

Comment: yes, I came across articles around 8 years old, I just wanted to be sure that nothing has still changed. Because it is a huge limitation.